# Compile Error: fatal error: 'eosiolib/eosio.hpp' file not found

Tags: eosio.cdt, eosio-cpp

eosio.cdt version 1.6.2

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10

Code Contract

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>

using eosio::contract;
using eosio::print;
using eosio::name;

CONTRACT hello : public contract {

    public:
        using contract::contract;

        ACTION greet (name user) {
            print("Hello world, hello ", name{user}, "!");
        };

};

EOSIO_DISPATCH(hello, (greet));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, you should use `eosio-init` to set up a new helloworld contract. It generates a build with cmake that works without you having to do things manually on the command line.

To run `eosio-init` and create a project called helloworld, type the following:

```
eosio-init --project=helloworld
```

If you must use `eosio-cpp` directly, then maybe you need to include the `-I` flag to indicate where the compiler should look for header files?

It could also be that the `eosio.cdt` you installed didn't install correctly or fully, it can definitely cause problems if you install more than one version of `eosio.cdt`, for example via `apt` and also via Github